# How to change achemso's citation style in tables?

Tags: citing, achemso

The standard citation style when using `\cite` in an `achemso` document creates a superscript with the reference number and links to the reference in the biblography. However, when creating a column inside a table, which contains the references (e.g. of some data specified in a previous column), I want the reference number to be typeset like normal text and not as a superscript. Is there a way to achieve this by either using a different command or setting a key which changes the behavior of the `\cite` command? Or is this intended behavior and tables should not contain the reference numbers as normal text?

Here is a minimal working example that produces the undesired result. The reference numbers should not be typeset as a superscript inside this table.

Main document (`main.tex`):

```
\documentclass{achemso}

\title{Example}
\author{Some Author}
\affiliation{Some University}
\email{some.author@email.com}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l l c}
        \hline
        Data & Value & Reference \\
        \hline
        First Quantity & Some Value & \cite{Abernethy2003} \\
        Second Quantity & Another Value & \cite{Arduengo1992} \\
        \dots & \dots & \dots \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table containing data and their references.}
\end{table}

\bibliography{references.bib}

\end{document}
```

Biblography database (`references.bib`):

```
@ARTICLE{Abernethy2003,
  author = {Colin D. Abernethy and Gareth M. Codd and Mark D. Spicer
    and Michelle K. Taylor},
  title = {A highly stable {N}-heterocyclic carbene complex of
    trichloro-oxo-vanadium(\textsc{v}) displaying novel
    {Cl}---{C}(carbene) bonding interactions},
  journal = {J.~Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year = {2003},
  volume = {125},
  pages = {1128--1129},
  number = {5},
  doi = {10.1021/ja0276321},
}

@ARTICLE{Arduengo1992,
  author = {Arduengo, III, Anthony J. and H. V. Rasika Dias and
    Richard L. Harlow and Michael Kline},
  title = {Electronic stabilization of nucleophilic carbenes},
  journal = {J.~Am.\ Chem.\ Soc.},
  year = {1992},
  volume = {114},
  pages = {5530--5534},
  number = {14},
  doi = {10.1021/ja00040a007},
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be better if you used citations instead of fake superscripts.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:  You achieve the desired result by using the `\citenum{...}` command.

I found out `achemso` uses `natbib` (as stated in the "Requirements" section of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/achemso/achemso.pdf)), meaning you have access to its various citation commands, including `\citenum{...}`. Some commands are explained in section 7, "The natmove package", or showcased in `achemso-demo` (section "References", code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/josephwright/achemso/blob/0e20e36933c08174ecca7fde5d584d6338f41d96/achemso-demo.tex#L160)).

I also found out that although setting the key `super` to `false` with `\setkeys{acs}{super=false}` changes the citation style, it still typesets the reference number as a superscript when using the regular `\cite`. To be precise, the class executes following commands, which result in italicized reference numbers in round parentheses:

```
\setcitestyle{round}
\renewcommand*\citenumfont{\textit}
```